# Dosa on clad stainless steel pan

Tags: frying, indian-cuisine, stainless-steel

Has anyone had success at making dosa on a clad stainless steel pan?

I mimicked the method for [frying eggs on clad stainless steel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbALNwE5cCQ) (medium heat, when drops of water dance, add fat, spread room-temperature batter, wait with lots of patience) -- but the dosa sticks.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  My experience is that dosa batter is extremely sticky, and can only be cooked on either nonstick or very well seasoned griddles.  Will be interested to see if anyone comes up with something that works.

Comment: @FuzzyChef would oat pancake batter be as sticky as dosa batter? If so, this video shows oat pancakes on 4 different clad stainless steel pans: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3K25wQknokM

Comment: Dosa batter is worse.  It's sticky, *and* it's also very fragile due to the lack of any gluten.

Comment: Try "seasoning" the pan by heating and towelling the oil two or more times before cooking. as seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kd9bIO8y2Aw